# JSON ignoring @XmlElement (name="xxx") annotation

Tags: json, jaxb, annotations

I have a lot of VO's that must have it's atributes names changed when I turn it's values for a JSON format, and JSON ignore my @XmlElement(name = "xxxx") annotations, giving the output with the atributes original names.

Fast sample:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Car {

    @XmlElement(name = "version")
    public String model;

    @XmlElement(name = "manufacturer")
    public String brand;
```

and the JSON output is:

```
{"model":"Camaro","brand":"Chevrolet"}
```

but I need it to be:

```
{"version":"Camaro","manufacturer":"Chevrolet"}
```

I can't change the atributes names. 
Is it possible to JSON understand this?

Comment: The way I figured it out, was to just generate the Xml files from the VO's with the names updated from the annotations, and then generate the Json output from the Xml files. But I still would like to make it happen directly from the vo's.

Answer (score 0):

use can use @JsonProperty if it is possible to change your object class.

or see this link [Unmarshalling json by reversing the affect of @XmlElement renaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731868/unmarshalling-json-by-reversing-the-affect-of-xmlelement-renaming)
to apply JAXB annotation for generating JSON output.